# Typescript: confused with "declaration: true" rule

Tags: typescript

Assuming I have a `app.ts` file:

```
interface IApp {}
export class App implements IApp {}
```

With `declaration` set to `true` in tsconfig.json, I will get an error:

```
error TS4019: Implements clause of exported class 'App' has or is using private name 'IApp'.
```

However, if I declare `IApp` in another file and import it, the problem will be resolved:

```
import { IApp } from './interface';
export class App implements IApp {}
```

In my view, both of the two implementations are using the private variable `IApp` in `app.ts` file scope, so why the first one fails but the second succeeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

```
export interface IApp {}
```

The second one works because you need to have exported that interface in the other file in order to work with it.

---

Details can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6307#issuecomment-168321011)

> This error occurs when you use the --declaration flag because the compiler is trying to produce a declaration file that exactly matches the module you defined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The definition of "private" is really weird here. As for me, both of the two examples are using private name "IApp" in `app.ts` file but only the first one fails. So as you've explained, once I export an interface somewhere, it will be regarded as a "public" (or an "exported") interface in my project, there's no need to export it again in where I am using it - is it right?

Comment: @Dolphin_Wood Yes once something is exported it's no more private. This error essentially says that without exporting IApp it's impossible to generate proper declaration file for `App` class, fixing it by exporting IApp once is sufficient: now you can have another module with  `import {App} from '...'; export class App2 extends App {}` which compiles just fine.

Comment: @Dolphin_Wood each module is javascript is regarded as having public and private members (its exports vs. its closure) that's the private it's referring to. Maybe non-exported would be a clearer term, but once you understand the module exports system both are pretty clear. There's no need to export it again, you are correct.